# how to handle 500 error

Tags: aem

I'm trying to show custom error message for 404/403/500 error. I'm able to show 404/403 error but unable to show 500 error.  Steps I have followed so far -

**Step 1**: Created a servlet which will set the status as 500

```
   public class ErrorServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(final SlingHttpServletRequest request,
            final SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
                try{
                  response.setStatus(500);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
```

**Step2**: Crated Exception.jsp and Throwable.jsp under apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler

**Step3**: Added below code in both Exception.jsp and Throwable.jsp

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>  
<%@taglib prefix="sling" uri="http://sling.apache.org/taglibs/sling/1.0" %><% 
%><sling:defineObjects /><%
 response.setStatus(500);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/content/myproject/en_US/
  errorpages/errorpage500.html").forward(request,response); %>
```

Now when I hit __http://port:host/path/to/servlet then I get "Internal Server Error" in the browser. It does not send to the expected custom error page which I mentioned. 
Kindly let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: overlay default.jsp under /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler and added above code, after it was fine. Not sure why Exception.jsp/Throwable.jsp did not work

Comment: Man there are so less people working on CQ5 nobody is there to answer. I have been struggling with a similar issue for a long long time now.

Comment: See if this helps http://www.minzdravkub.ru/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__1hrp-hi_we_have_creat.html

Comment: link in comment is dead, Oliver is right.. so few people working on CQ5. at least, in this community.