# AEM - Custom error handler not reflecting error code for 500

Tags: java, aem

I've overridden the OOTB error handler and it works fine for 404 pages.

For 500 error, I've created a Throwable.jsp and inside the calling service class which internally set the response code 500 and forward the request.

For the 404, since the resource doesn't exist, in that case, it doesn't make any call to any of AEM resource and hence directly jump 
to error handler and render the error page (could be via include, forward or sendRedirect - all works in this case)

But, for 500, since the actual page resource exist but only let's say a component in page having some issue in backend and due to that it throws 500 error. But, before that, we have an authentication handler running which actually sets the anonymous token and cookie on the page and that could be the reason while I try to set 500 and try to do sendRedirect or forward, in that case, it shows **Response already committed**.

With include, it does work 'cos in that case, it includes the error page resource inside actual rendering page and include doesn't change the status of rendering page.

Considering the use case, what could be the implementation approach?

Comment: you could try to set 500 error page in apache httpd config

Comment: @SumantaPakira I've a doubt here. Since, the overall page return 200 status then in that case how the apache will figure out about 500 error. Or is there any way to configure error handler part on apache which actually figure out if any part of code breaks and internally throws error?
E.g. Let's say 10 components are there on page out of which 1 component logic breaks and hence cause breaking of entire page but still page status is 200. In that case, how can apache figured out that something didn't work out and can return 500?

Comment: Ok, I did not understand it first, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452304/how-to-handle-500-error

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about Author or Publish environments? On an author you might need to disable the  CQ WCM Debug Filter.

Comment: Only checking it on Publish instance.

Comment: Even there somebody might have activated the debug filter. OOTB it is disabled on publish, but you never know...